# Error in Android Studio Build (version 1.2.1.1) and Gradle (version 1.2.3)

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Since upgrading to AS 1.2.x I cannot build my project.

Every time I build (or clean or Invalidate Caches/Restart) I get the following error message:

[image]

My gradle build files are as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
        {
    signingConfigs {
        config {            keyAlias 'ScoularAndroidKey'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/bschmiedeler/.AndroidStudio/scoularkeystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
    name="Scoular"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.scoular.scoular"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug{
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile files('src/main/assets/library-1.0.10.jar')
}
```

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: I believe I am using version 1.2.3.

Comment: 1.2.3 is the version of the gradle plugin. The version of the gradle is inside the gradle-wrapper.properties file

Comment: OK so I find that that is 1.2.3 as well.#Tue May 26 16:42:57 CDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.2.3-all.zip